# как сделать математические действия в bat среди переменных

Tags: bat

как сделать математические действия в bat среди переменных.
как вычесть переменную goblin_hp от hero_damage

```
set /a goblin_hp=4
set /a hero_damage=3
set /p answer=выбирай
if %answer%==1 %goblin_hp% - %hero_damage%
echo ты ударил гоблина и у него осталось %goblin_hp%
pause
```

Comment: 1.Ударить
2.Ничего не делать
Press any key to continue . . .
выбирай1
'4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ты ударил гоблина и у него осталось 4
Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 0):

В самом простом варианте вам нужно лишь присвоить вычисленное значение переменной:

```
if %answer%==1 set /a goblin_hp = %goblin_hp% - %hero_damage%
```

Но остальная часть кода (сообщение об остатке goblin_hp) будет выполняться независимо от того, ударили гоблина или нет. Можно сделать так:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a goblin_hp=4
set /a hero_damage=3
set /p answer=Выбирай: 
if %answer%==1 (
    set /a goblin_hp = %goblin_hp% - %hero_damage%
    echo Ты ударил гоблина и у него осталось !goblin_hp!
)
pause
```

Пояснения относительно `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` и `!goblin_hp!` - [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9102569/15035314).

Можно попроще, c goto:

```
@echo off
set /a goblin_hp=4
set /a hero_damage=3
set /p answer=Выбирай: 
if %answer% NEQ 1 goto out
set /a goblin_hp = %goblin_hp% - %hero_damage%
echo Ты ударил гоблина и у него осталось %goblin_hp%
:out
pause
```

Comment: для чего используется NEQ И goto out

Comment: NEQ это не равно. goto это переход к метке

Comment: разобрался, спасибо за ответ